# Php sort array on based of another array and one sub array field

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to create an application which find near by restaurants, I have used a database to retrieve near by zipcodes

so I now have an array like

```
$sortLike=array(60007,60001,60003,60002);
```

and database return array like

```
$array1= array( array ('ID' => 138,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 1),
                array('ID' => 103,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 0),
                array('ID' => 124,'zip_code' => 60002,'approved' => 0),
                array('ID' => 104,'zip_code' => 60002,'approved' => 1),
                array('ID' => 105,'zip_code' => 60003,'approved' => 0),
                array('ID' => 106,'zip_code' => 60001,'approved' => 0),
                array('ID' => 114,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 0)
);
```

So I need to show all restaurants that are approved but in order of $sortLike array
i.e returned array should be

```
   $array1= array(  
                    array ('ID' => 138,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 1),
                    array('ID' => 103,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 0),
                    array('ID' => 114,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 0)
                    array('ID' => 106,'zip_code' => 60001,'approved' => 0),
                    array('ID' => 105,'zip_code' => 60003,'approved' => 0),
                    array('ID' => 104,'zip_code' => 60002,'approved' => 1),
                    array('ID' => 124,'zip_code' => 60002,'approved' => 0),
    );
```

Here is what I tried

```
function sortarray1($mylist,$mainZipSearch){
    $newList=$newList2=$newList3 = array();
    $j=$k=$l=0;
    if(count($mylist))
    {
        foreach($mylist as $k=>$v) {
            if( $v['approved']==1 && $v['zip_code']==$mainZipSearch){
                    $newList[$j]    =   $mylist[$k];
            } 
            else if( $v['approved']==0 && $v['zip_code']==$mainZipSearch){
                    $newList2[$k]   =   $mylist[$k];    
            }
            else{
                    $newList3[$l]   =   $mylist[$k]; 
            }
            $j++;$k++;$l++;
        }
        $newList=array_values($newList);
        $newList2=array_values($newList2);
        $newList3=array_values($newList3);
        $arr=array_merge($newList,$newList2,$newList3 );
    }
    return
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going way too far !

Using [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) makes such problems easier to handle.

```
function sort_results ($a, $b) {
   $sortLike=array(60007,60001,60003,60002);
   // Push unknown values at the end of the array
   if (!in_array ($a['zip_code'], $sortLike)) { return 1; } 
   return array_search($a['zip_code'], $sortLike) > array_search($b['zip_code'], $sortLike);
}

usort ($arr, 'sort_results');

print_r ($arr);

Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [ID] => 114 [zip_code] => 60007 [approved] => 0 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [ID] => 103 [zip_code] => 60007 [approved] => 0 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [ID] => 138 [zip_code] => 60007 [approved] => 1 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [ID] => 106 [zip_code] => 60001 [approved] => 0 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [ID] => 105 [zip_code] => 60003 [approved] => 0 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [ID] => 124 [zip_code] => 60002 [approved] => 0 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [ID] => 104 [zip_code] => 60002 [approved] => 1 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [ID] => 184 [zip_code] => 60022 [approved] => 0 )
)
```

Comment: if the database array have an element which is not not in the sortLike array it places right after 60007 please try this input
$array1= array(array ('ID' => 138,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 1),array('ID' => 103,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 0), array('ID' => 124,'zip_code' => 60002,'approved' => 0), array('ID' => 104,'zip_code' => 60002,'approved' => 1), array('ID' => 105,'zip_code' => 60003,'approved' => 0), array('ID' => 106,'zip_code' => 60001,'approved' => 0), array('ID' => 114,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 0),array('ID' => 184,'zip_code' => 60022,'approved' => 0) );

Comment: @June I don't really get your point, and what you would like to do in that case ? You can easily change the `sort_results` function to check if `in_array ($sortLike, $a)` and handle this case to place it in the end for example.

Comment: function should place such a thing in the end so that if it doesnt exist it should go in the end

Comment: @June Edited my answer, it's working as you want now.

Comment: this works but if you could somehow check if 60022(not in sortlike array) is 2 times once with approved 0 and than with approved 1 , in this scenario 60022 with approved should come first

Comment: @June Hey I won't make your whole code after each comment. I helped you on this problem because you actually tried something and you were lost, but I'm sure you can do things now (look at `pop` or `push` functions). And if you don't manage to do it, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This is why we have relational databases. If you have a query which returns the sorted list of Zipcodes, then simply join the query which returns the approved restaurants.

Comment: lol :D "order by whatever_it_needs_ordered_by_probably_distance;"

Comment: Yeah but the data is further in different tables so I had to get the data in 1 query and sort on compile time

Comment: I am struggling to come up with a civil response to this comment. That you are using the term tables implies you *are* using a relational database (although even most non-relational databases support some sort of JOIN capability). No, you do not to run one query for each table. This is very rudimentary database programming.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<?
$sortLike=array(60007,60001,60003,60002);
$array1= array( array ('ID' => 138,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 1),
                array('ID' => 103,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 0),
                array('ID' => 124,'zip_code' => 60002,'approved' => 0),
                array('ID' => 104,'zip_code' => 60002,'approved' => 1),
                array('ID' => 105,'zip_code' => 60003,'approved' => 0),
                array('ID' => 106,'zip_code' => 60001,'approved' => 0),
                array('ID' => 114,'zip_code' => 60007,'approved' => 0)
);

function removeNonApproved($var) {
    return $var['approved'];
}

function cmp($a,$b) {
    global $sortLike;
    return (array_search($a['zip_code'],$sortLike) < array_search($b['zip_code'],$sortLike) ) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Remove non approved items
$array1 = array_filter($array1,"removeNonApproved");

// Sort your array
usort($array1, "cmp");

var_dump($array1);

?>
```